# how to fix jdk directory not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an app with ionic but it says :

> Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
>   You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
>   Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin

I have jdk installed in: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin` and I've already set it up in Edit environment variables.
and `jdk1.8.0_211` has been removed already.

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1"